# AJAX DELETE Method Redirect Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I am trying to fix my jQuery AJAX command where there is a click on a `<a href="#">` which triggers a `DELETE` request for the specific url that I have a route setup for and then redirect to a new page. The `DELETE` portion of my AJAX is working correctly, but for some reason, the success portion is interpreting my redirect to `/app` as a `DELETE` request. It doesn't seem to recognize the `GET` I have set up before the URL and is defaulting to `DELETE`. Can anyone help me determine what part of my method is incorrect?

Link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="card-delete-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>DELETE</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#card-delete-link').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    url: '/app/edit/{{card.cardId}}',
                    success: function(){
                        console.log('Annotation ID: ' + '{{card.cardId}}' + ' was deleted');
                        $.ajax({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url:'/app'
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Browser Console:

```
jquery.js:8630 DELETE http://localhost:3000/app 404 (Not Found)
```

Route:

```
appRoutes.route('/edit/:cardId')
    .delete(function(req, res){
        models.Card.destroy({
            where: {
                userId: req.user.userId,
                cardId: req.params.cardId           
            }
        }).then(function(){
            res.redirect('/app');
        });
    });
```

Comment: try adding an `error:` handler to both calls, maybe something there...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node.js you are using .delete verb, it means it will ignore all requests except those with DELETE method stipulated in headers. This is why your GET request is not handled. Thereby, you could easily redirect on success with **window.location.replace()** without making a second request to the server. On the other hand, if making second request is critical, just create a new a route

Example:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage');
});
```

Also, you should rethink your code, because you won't be able to redirect with ajax request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was very insightful. I understand what you are saying, but what would you recommend outside of the ajax request? I feel like the `.delete` is best practices for deleting a database record, but the issue is that I can't figure out how to use an HTML element to trigger that method without ajax. I feel like once this is achieved then the redirect on my route would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Inside of success:function() {}, after console.log() and instead of $.ajax just write window.location.replace('/app')